# Shallow parsing with ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to develop a solution able to extract, in a closed-context, certain actions.

For example, in a context of booking cinema tickets, if a user says:

"I'd like to go to the cinema tomorrow night, it would be Casablanca, I'd like to be at the last row, please"

I've designed grammars for getting the name of the film, desired seat, date and hour of the projection, etc.

However, though I've thought about ANTLR for developing such solution, I don't really know if it has such functionality, I mean, if I can define several root symbols.

Answer (score 3):

ANTLR has methods of addressing ambiguities in grammars. These methods are in improved in ANTLR 4, but when it comes to processing ambiguous languages (especially human language), you'll face one giant limitation that will inevitably make ANTLR unsuitable for the task:

ANTLR eventually resolves an ambiguity by deciding that one specific option among multiple potential options is *the* correct solution. Since this resolution happens at a very early stage in the parsing process with ANTLR, it's very difficult to incorporate semantic logic in this decision making process (as opposed to logic involving syntax alone).

Edit: One thing that's particularly interesting about ANTLR 4 in the context of NLP is the fact that ANTLR 4 uses an [augmented transition network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_transition_network) as the basis for its parser. Somewhere in there I know it would be possible to modify it for use in natural language processing, but to date haven't figured out just how to make it work. Reference: I developed the [optimized](http://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/tree/optimized) version of the ANTLR 4 runtime, which is currently slightly behind the reference branch but I'll catch up later this summer.

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR isn't well suited to parse *human* languages: they're too ambiguous. Try [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) instead. Here's a list of [natural language processing toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at those alternatives.
Anyway, is there any way for identifying certain actions into a sentence with ANTLR?

Comment: @adsuar, *"is there any way for identifying certain actions into a sentence with ANTLR? "*, sure, however, a NLP toolkit will do this much better. And these toolkits come with grammars for language(s) you can use out of the box: with ANTLR you'd need to write your own grammar (which will never ever come close to reliably parsing a wide range of English sentences!).

Comment: as far as i can see at the list of software you facilitated me, almost every software given has an important statistical effort by means of corpora and I have a great lack or corpora right now. That's why I was wondering about **shallow parsing** at ANTLR, since I can develop tiny grammars for capturing certain concepts.

Comment: Not sure in how many different ways I can tell you ANTLR isn't well suited for this task... I appears you've got your mind set on ANTLR, and are hoping to get confirmation on SO. By all means, go the ANTLR-way! :)

Comment: Don't worry. You convinced me about that, I gave up. Anyway, I was interested about Shallow Parsing at ANTLR and, as far as i can see, it is not possible right now.